# C++ preparedstatement

Tags: c++, arguments, prepared-statement

How do i set the prepared statement accordingly to its data type from the retrieved string and its variables, using MySQL C++ Connector? Eg. the function receives a sql query, and values, then this function is to make it into a prepared statement and return the execution?

```
int Testing(initializer_list<any> args) {
    for(const auto &arg : args) {
            if(arg.type() == typeid(int)) { // Check for int
                    int value = any_cast<int>(arg);
                    cout << "Int value: " << value << endl;

                    //set into prepared statement according to its data type

            } else if(arg.type() == typeid(string)) {
                    string value = any_cast<string>(arg);
                    cout << "String value: " << value << endl;

                    //set into prepared statement according to its data type

            }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    Testing({std::string("Insert into table(field1, field2)VALUES(?,?)", 1 , string('thistring'))});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should look into [*parameter packs*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), as well as [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream). The [parameter pack reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) even have an example almost doing exactly what you want.

Comment: Besides that, doesn't most SQL (and other database connectivity) libraries come with functionality to *bind* arguments to specific positions in a query string?

Comment: What did you find when you searched for "MySQL C++ Connector prepared statement" on Google, and why did the documentation and the dozens of examples not work for you?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I've worked with mysqlcppconn. Unfortunately the interface is modelled on the jdbc interface. You have to write your own variadic plumbing (see below).

Answer (score 0):

Unhappily the oracle mysqlcppconn interface is modelled on an ancient java idea.

This means you're going to have to apply your own variadic plumbing.

It's not that hard, as long as you're happy to choose some standard mappings between c++ types and SQL types.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

// simulate mysql class

struct PreparedStatement
{
    PreparedStatement(std::string const& sql) {};

    void setString(std::size_t column, const std::string& value) {};
    void setInt(std::size_t column, int value) {};

};

namespace detail {

    //
    // these overloads perform the correct action depending on the argument type
    //
    void parameterise(PreparedStatement& stmt, std::size_t column, std::string const& value) {
        stmt.setString(column, value);
    }

    void parameterise(PreparedStatement& stmt, std::size_t column, const char* value) {
        stmt.setString(column, value);
    }

    void parameterise(PreparedStatement& stmt, std::size_t column, int value) {
        stmt.setInt(column, value);
    }


    //
    // variadic parameteriser
    //
    template<class Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
    void parameterise(PreparedStatement& stmt, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::size_t initial_index = 1)
    {
        using expand = int[];
        void(expand { 0,
                 (parameterise(stmt, Is + initial_index, std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))),0)...
        });
    };
}

template<class...Args>
auto build_parameterised_query(const std::string sql, Args&&...args)
{
    //
    // in mysqcppconn, this bit would be
    // auto stmt = std::unique_ptr<PreparedStatement>(connection->preparedStatement(sql));
    //
    auto stmt = std::make_unique<PreparedStatement>(sql);

    // but the rest would be the same

    detail::parameterise(*stmt,
                         std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
                         std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>());
    return stmt;

}

int main()
{
    auto stmt = build_parameterised_query("SELECT * from foo where a = ? and b = ? and c = ?",
                                          std::string("bar"),
                                          "baz",
                                          6);
}
```